# Email verfication token error using prima and nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, prisma, tanstackreact-query

I am getting prisma error of PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.verificationToken.findUnique()` invocation when render the verify-email page in my application.

Here is my verify-email page code:

```
"use client";

import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import { Mail, RotateCw } from "lucide-react";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { toast } from "sonner";

const SendEmail = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const token = searchParams.get("token");

  const { mutate: verifyEmail } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (token: string) => {
      const payload: string = JSON.stringify(token);
      console.log(payload);
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/auth/verify-email", payload);
      return data as string;
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return toast(error.message);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {},
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;
    verifyEmail(token as string);
  }, [verifyEmail, token]);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
      <Mail className="mb-2 h-7 w-7" />
      <h1 className="mb-2 text-center text-2xl font-bold">
        Confirming your verification
      </h1>
      <p className="mb-4 rounded-md border  bg-gray-50 p-2.5 text-xs text-gray-400">
        {token}
      </p>
      <RotateCw className="h-8 w-8 animate-spin" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SendEmail;
```

**Email Verify Route Page**

```
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/data";
import { prisma } from "@/prisma/client";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body = await req.json();
  const { token } = body;

  // if token does not exist
  const existedToken = await prisma.verificationToken.findUnique({
    where: {
      token,
    },
  });
  if (!existedToken) {
    return new Response("Token does not exist.", { status: 404 });
  }

  // if token is expired
  const hasExpired = new Date(existedToken.expires) < new Date();
  if (hasExpired) {
    return new Response("Token has expired.", { status: 422 });
  }

  // if user change the email
  const existedUser = await getUserByEmail(existedToken.email);
  if (!existedUser) {
    return new Response("Email does not exist.", { status: 404 });
  }

  // updating email verification
  await prisma.user.update({
    where: { id: existedUser.id },
    data: {
      emailVerified: new Date(),
      email: existedToken.email,
    },
  });

  // deleting verification token
  await prisma.verificationToken.delete({
    where: {
      id: existedToken.id,
    },
  });

  return new Response("Email verified!", { status: 201 });
}
```

**Error**

⨯ PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.verificationToken.findUnique()` invocation:

{

- where: {
- AND: VerificationTokenWhereInput | VerificationTokenWhereInput[],
- OR: VerificationTokenWhereInput[],
- NOT: VerificationTokenWhereInput | VerificationTokenWhereInput[],
- id: StringFilter | String,
- email: StringFilter | String,
- token: StringFilter | String,
- expires: DateTimeFilter | DateTime
- }
  }

Argument `where` is missing.

⨯ PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.verificationToken.findUnique()` invocation:

{

- where: {
- AND: VerificationTokenWhereInput | VerificationTokenWhereInput[],
- OR: VerificationTokenWhereInput[],
- NOT: VerificationTokenWhereInput | VerificationTokenWhereInput[],
- id: StringFilter | String,
- email: StringFilter | String,
- token: StringFilter | String,
- expires: DateTimeFilter | DateTime
- }
  }
  clientVersion: '5.8.0'
  }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uDcz.png)

I want verify my token and return back to user login page using tanstackreact-query and axios.